# What's the correct GraphQL behaviour when error occured in the middle of execution of multiple mutations?

Tags: graphql

Let's say we have the following query (taken from the spec):

```
mutation Root {
  first: changeTheNumber(newNumber: 1) {
    theNumber
  }
  second: changeTheNumber(newNumber: 3) {
    theNumber
  }
  third: changeTheNumber(newNumber: 2) {
    theNumber
  }
}
```

Assuming the error occured during execution of second mutation, how GraphQL server implementation should act in such case: should the third mutation be evaluated or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JavaScript reference implementation for GraphQL](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/3cf66f33e30d467b068b4054e120562b01d885b7/src/execution/execute.js#L286-L322), the same mutation `changeTheNumber` of the selection set will be executed in the given order. If error occurs in the second mutation, its [result will be an Error object](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/3cf66f33e30d467b068b4054e120562b01d885b7/src/execution/execute.js#L584). The following mutations in that selection set will not be aborted.